# How to update npm package readme file without updating version?

Tags: javascript, npm, package, npm-start

When I need to update my npm package `readme` file , I need to update it's version. Is it possible to update `readme` file without version update?

Comment: If you're following Semver guidelines, (if not then you should be!), then _no_ because doing so would be a breach of the rules.  See point [`#3`](https://semver.org/#spec-item-3) in the semver spec. It reads: _"Once a versioned package has been released, the contents of that version MUST NOT be modified. Any modifications MUST be released as a new version."_.

Comment: @RobC If you're anything less than a god, then it's possible to make a mistake in the Readme, especially since English isn't the first language of most programmers and it doesn't have convenient static analysis tools to make sure that what we write is correct and true. Also, the following are assumed to be excluded from versioning unless explicitly stated

- guarantees that any particular invalid usage will never become valid

- the text of human-readable error messages

- Non-code, such as documentation

Comment: Any progress on this one?

Comment: I want too to edit the readme file of my published Nuget without publishing a new version through the Nuget.org website.